# AndroidStudio check out project from github,but when open the project prompt " Error Loading Project: Cannot load 2 modules Details..."

Tags: git, bash, android-studio

When I create project in AndroidStudio，I select "check out project from version control ",then I select git,I clone  project from github,it is successed,but when I open the project,nothing to show and it is prompt "Error Loading Project: Cannot load 2 modules Details...",I can not resolve it,but when I use git bash clone the project and then I open the project in AndroidStudio it is successful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the hidden .idea folder from your project root folder and restart Android Studio, the system will rebuild these files and should be able to build the rest of the project.